# Nullpointerexception in chekcing page source with JavascriptExecutor

Tags: java, selenium, nullpointerexception, webdriver

I need to check if text in on the website. According to [driver.getPageSource() converts signs < to &lt;](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29517416/driver-getpagesource-converts-signs-to-lt) I tried to avoid `getPageSource()`. I need to use my function in various files, so I thought I can make it in the different file and write a code just once.

This is a file, which I wrote just for checking page source:

```
package pl.mainfolder.tests.selenium;

import static org.junit.Assert.fail;

import org.openqa.selenium.JavascriptExecutor;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;

public class CheckSource {
private WebDriver driver;

public void CheckSite(String textToBeChecked, String error)
        throws Exception {
    Object test = (((JavascriptExecutor) driver)
            .executeScript("return document.body.innerHTML;"));
    if (!((String) test).contains(textToBeChecked)) {
        fail(error);
    }
}
}
```

I tried to start that code with:

```
package pl.mainfolder.tests.selenium;

import static org.junit.Assert.fail;

import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

import org.junit.After;
import org.junit.Before;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.JavascriptExecutor;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;

import pl.mainfolder.tests.selenium.utils.WebDriverUtil;

public class LoginTest {
private WebDriver driver;
private String baseUrl;
private final StringBuffer verificationErrors = new StringBuffer();
public CheckSource Source = new CheckSource();

@Before
public void setUp() throws Exception {
    driver = WebDriverUtil.getFirefoxWebDriver();
    driver.manage().deleteAllCookies();
    baseUrl = "https://google.com/";
    driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
}

@Test
public void Login() throws Exception {
    driver.get(baseUrl);
    Source.CheckSite("Log in", "Error1");
(...)
```

And still got error NullPointerExcepiton

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
at pl.mainfolder.tests.selenium.CheckSource.CheckSite(CheckSource.java:14)
at pl.mainfolder.tests.selenium.LoginPLTest.Login(LoginPLTest.java:33)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:44)
at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:15)
at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:41)
at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:20)
at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:28)
at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunAfters.evaluate(RunAfters.java:31)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:263)
at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:69)
at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:48)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:231)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:60)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:229)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:50)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:222)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:292)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:50)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:459)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:675)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:382)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:192)
```

I tried with try-catch, but the code for checking wasn't working (everything was great and no problems, absolutely, even when on the site wasn't text "Logggginnnnn") and try to mix it with "if" (again the same)
Trying adding `else{}` made the NPE error again.

When I paste a code

```
public void CheckSite(String textToBeChecked, String error)
    throws Exception {
Object test = (((JavascriptExecutor) driver)
        .executeScript("return document.body.innerHTML;"));
if (!((String) test).contains(textToBeChecked)) {
    fail(error);
}
}
```

directly to all files, it works perfectly.

How can I handle it?

Comment: You are not initializing driver in class _CheckSource_.May be you need to add this line `driver = WebDriverUtil.getFirefoxWebDriver();` ?

Comment: `public void CheckSite(String textToBeChecked, String error)
   throws Exception {
  driver = WebDriverUtil.getFirefoxWebDriver();` this way? It opens me a new window, then looks there for a word, so it doens't work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yeah the error is indeed because driver is not getting initialized in class `CheckSource`. You may want to do below change.

*Change in LoginTest*

```
@Test
public void Login() throws Exception {
    driver.get(baseUrl);
    Source.CheckSite("Log in", "Error1",driver);// pass the instantiated driver object.
```

}

*In class CheckSource*

```
public void CheckSite(String textToBeChecked, String error,WebDriver driver)
        throws Exception {
    Object test = (((JavascriptExecutor) driver)
            .executeScript("return document.body.innerHTML;"));
    if (!((String) test).contains(textToBeChecked)) {
        fail(error);
    }
}
```

This will not give you NPE, in addition it is passing test case for Text=Sign in, offered.

*Note*: It will fail the test if you are checking *Log in* as you have mentioned in your question. This is working for me. Give it a try.

Comment: Works great! I forgot I can give WebDriver aswell :) and "Log in" I used just for an example :)